# vex prefixes and intrinsics

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

[Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions) on AVX says:

> The VEX prefix can also be used on the legacy SSE instructions giving
>   them a three-operand form, and making them interact more efficiently
>   with AVX instructions without the need for VZEROUPPER and ZEROALL.

My question is:

Does `-mavx` affect the legacy SSE/SSE2/SSE3/SSSE3/SSE4.1/SSE4.2 intrinsics in some way and how? Do the instructions they emit gain the VEX prefix automatically? Which (legacy) instruction sets are covered?

Comment: info gcc, i386 and x86-64 Options: `GCC depresses SSEx instructions when '-mavx' is used.  Instead, it generates new AVX instructions or AVX equivalence for all SSEx instructions when needed.` Reading the manual can sometimes be helpful.

Comment: Sure, but we ask for SSEx intrinsics explicitly. Both gcc/clang can generate SIMD code without the user's knowledge.

Comment: @user1095108 when in doubt try it out: https://goo.gl/cZXB7Q (the answer is yes btw.)

Comment: But it is not a complete answer, which SSE instruction sets does AVX cover? Some are more exotic than others.

Comment: @user1095108 you should probably ask "how does it affect.." instead of "Does it affect" then. In your question, not in the comments.